# Disable login screen on Ubuntu 15.04 (Vivid Vervet)

Tags: ubuntu, lightdm

In 15.04 Vivid Vervet, how do I disable the login screen so that it drops me into a console right off the bat? Back on 14.04, I did this by uninstalling lightdm, but when I tried that on 15.04, the system then wouldn't boot. :(

If you're wondering why I'm on 15.04, I bought a new Thinkpad X250 and need the drivers for the mouse buttons and touchpad.

Thank you!

Comment: 15.04 is (still) a development release, so all problems should be [raised on Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/) so that the developers can have a look at it and solve your problem for you and all future users that might have the same problem... **;-)**

Comment: Oh, thank you, I will do that! It had not occurred to me that this might be a bug. ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved my problem using this [very helpful answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16371/how-do-i-disable-x-at-boot-time-so-that-the-system-boots-in-text-mode) here. (It's the one with the green check mark. I recommend you also read the comments as I hit a snag and this led to the answer being amended.)

Also, I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/lightdm/+bug/1441883) about the system not booting without lightdm and it should be fixed by now.